# Spring MVC populate dynamically constant values in javascript

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I would like to populate JavaScript constant from property file, Anyone has better suggestions?

Here,

Property file,

```
property_timeout_Success=60000
property_timeout_Failure=10000
```

Java Script,

```
var config = {
    timeout_Success: [property_timeout_Success value], 
    timeout_Failure: [property_timeout_Failure value]
};
```

I am using Spring mvc, what is best way to load [property_timeout_Success] value in JavaScript file?

Thanks

Comment: Is the javascript inside a `jsp` file?

Comment: No, its pure javascript file(.js)

Comment: Then you cannot. A `.js` file is a static file, it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement. I get the Property in my Spring MVC Controller, and then put it into the model:

```
...... 
model.addAttribute("property_timeout_Success", property_timeout_Success); 
......
```

In the web page, I get the value with JavaScript like this(JSP page):

```
......
var property_timeout_Success = ${property_timeout_Success};
......
```

Wish this can help you.

**UPDATE**

I use Ajax with JQuery. Spring MVC Controller gets the property and then returns the value as json to the web page. You can get the value:

```
......
    var price="";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yoururl.html',
        data: {item:item, oper:'find'},
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            price=data.price;
        }
    })
......
```

Comment: I got it, But my javascript is independent .js page and is not part of JSP. Do you have any other better suggestion?

Comment: Hi, @Suresh Panneerselvam, sorry for late reply. I have updated my answer.